# How to access nested state from redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a simple React App that has a redux store This is its structure

```
AppState Structur:
rawMarketData: {
    isLoading: boolean
    results?: {
        date: string
        logs: [
            {
                sessionIndex: number
                time: string
                price: number
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
    error?: any  
}
```

I create a Test class component to access the state,
when I call the action to get the Data everything works fine
**But when I try to access the logs property (from the example above) I get undefined but when accessing results it works!**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

interface MarketDataLog {
    sessionIndex: number
    time: string
    price: number
}

interface RawMarketDataResults {
    date: string
    logs: MarketDataLog[]
}

interface RawMarketDataLogState {
    isLoading: boolean
    results?: RawMarketDataResults
    error?: any
}

interface AppState {
    rawMarketData: RawMarketDataLogState
}
//All of the above is the app state structure 



interface MyProps {
    rawData: RawMarketDataResults | undefined
}

class TestFile extends React.Component<MyProps> {
    render() {
        console.log('this is { results: { date, logs[] } }' + JSON.stringify(this.props.rawData)) //Works Good
        console.log('this is the { results: { logs[] } ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.rawData?.logs)) // Undefined

        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.rawData ? 'there is Data in State' : 'No data in state'}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => {
    return { rawData: state.rawMarketData.results }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestFile)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.props.rawData?.results?.logs`?

Comment: no, I get the results straight to props, when I log the whole `rawData` I get
`
{
date: 'some date'
logs: [
    {
    sessionIndex: 0
    time: 'datestring'
    price: '100'
    }, ...
]}

but the `logs` property on itself is undefined

Comment: I guess you don't need to check the isLoading value, that's just there for no reason at all? Could it be that data is not available because it is loading? What do the redux devtools say?

Comment: Dev tools says everything is fine, the action get dispatched and the state is filled

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was a missing [] in RawMarketDataResults

interface RawMarketDataLogState {
isLoading: boolean
results?: RawMarketDataResults[]
error?: any
}

**Fixed**